# How can i decrypt adler32 value in android

Tags: java, android

I'm encode my value in adler32 hash key. But how i decrypt adler32 value in android? I use https://github.com/BullyBoo/Encryption this libery for encrypt adler32. But i don't know that how decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

**Adler-32** is often mistaken for a `CRC`, but it is not, it is a `checksum`.

I can't find any relation between that library and **Adler-32** .

Anyway you can share more details for your purpose.

There are many non-cryptographic hash functions that are very fast and have good hash behavior, including avoidance of collisions. Take a look at the [CityHash](https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/) family of hash functions.

If you need cryptographic (non-spoofable) hash functions, then look at [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and [SHA-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3).